# how to execute a function that inside it is another function and pass params

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this :

```
$.SetInLocalStorageVideoTime = function (uuid) {

    alert(uuid);
    var Interval = setInterval(function () {

        localStorage.setItem('poption-ctime-'+ uuid , jwplayer("target").getPosition());

    },10000);

    var ClearInterVal = clearInterval(Interval);

    return {

        Interval : Interval,
        ClearInterVal : ClearInterVal
    }
};
```

My problem is how to call the `Interval` function and pass `uuid` param to that.

I have tried `$.SetInLocalStorageVideoTime("blahblah").Interval();` but it throws an error.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $.SetInLocalStorageVideoTime is not a function(…)`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $.SetInLocalStorageVideoTime(...).Interval is not a function`

Comment: $.SetInLocalStorageVideoTime("blahblah") 
returns Interval as a value not as a function hence cannot be called

Comment: could it be that it's a sequence issue? do you include zone.js before you declare that function?

Comment: `Interval` is the `id` of the interval, a number,  it's not a function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Interval = setInterval(...)
```

This immediately *calls* the `setInterval` function and assigns its return value to `Interval`; same for `clearInterval`. You don't want to call the function, you want to create a function which when called calls the function. Two ways to do that:

```
var Interval = function () {
    setInterval(...);
}

var Interval = setInterval.bind(null, ...);
```

Putting it all together, you want this:

```
$.SetInLocalStorageVideoTime = function (uuid) {
    var interval = null;

    var set = function () {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            localStorage.setItem('poption-ctime-'+ uuid , jwplayer("target").getPosition());
        }, 10000);
    };

    var clear = function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };

    return {
        Interval : set,
        ClearInterVal : clear
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Look this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/7H61Vv6m8M552CNeIpSA?p=preview

You must encapsulate into function :

```
var stop;
var interval =  function () { 
    stop = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(uuid);
    },100);
}

var ClearInterVal = function () { clearInterval(stop) };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several simple issues, you must export function that will clearTimeout

```
$.SetInLocalStorageVideoTime = function(uuid) {
  // auto start interval, you could
  // add starter function or something
  var Interval = setInterval(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('poption-ctime-' + uuid, jwplayer("target").getPosition());
  }, 10000);

  // clear function
  // exported
  var ClearInterVal = function() {
    if (Interval)
      clearInterval(Interval);
  }
  return {
    // Interval is not required here
    ClearInterVal: ClearInterVal
  }
};
$.SetInLocalStorageVideoTime();
```